# Linux find command, find 10 latest files recursively regardless of time span

Tags: linux, find, tail

What have I tried so far...

Command:

```
find . -type f -ctime -3 | tail -n 5
```

Result:

```
./Mobilni Telefoni/01. Box Update/05. DC Unlocker Client/dc-unlocker_client-1.00.0857.exe
./Mobilni Telefoni/01. Box Update/39. Z3X Box/01. Update/01. Samsung Box/SamsungTool_12.4.exe
./Mobilni Telefoni/10. Nokia/1. SRPSKI  HRVATSKI  JEZICI/BB5/3xx_Series/Asha 300/06.97/rm781_06.97_ppm_d.rar
./GPS Navigacije/01. Garmin/03. Garmin Other/garmin_kgen_15.exe
./GPS Navigacije/01. Garmin/03. Garmin Other/test.txt
```

This output is OK, doesn't work good if I put wider time span. (notice I use -ctime and not -mtime because some uploaded files are modified few years ago)

Problem is that files can be uploaded once a month, or once in a year, and I still need to get 10 latest files, regardless of time span.

If it can't be done, does `tail` only limit output, or somehow just fetches number specified without huge performance impact on large number of files.

By using command from one answer on SO, I was able to get the files but some files were missing...

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -10 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

Result:

```
./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2330/E2330_OXFKE2.rar
./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2330/FlashTool_E2_R6.zip
./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E210/E210_XFGH2.rar
./Mobilni Telefoni/05. iPhone/07. iFaith/iFaith-v1.4.1_windows-final.zip
./Mobilni Telefoni/05. iPhone/09. iPhone Browser/SetupiPhoneBrowser.1.93.exe
./Mobilni Telefoni/05. iPhone/10. iPhone_PC_Suite/iPhone_PC_Suite_Eng_v0.2.1.rar
./Mobilni Telefoni/05. iPhone/10. iPhone_PC_Suite/iPhone_PC_Suite_Ok.rar
./test
./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2152/E2152_XXJH4_OXFJI2.zip.filepart
./GPS Navigacije/01. Garmin/03. Garmin Other/test.txt
```

File `garmin_kgen_15.exe` is missing because it was created in 2008, but it was uploaded in last 24 hours.

Comment: Which time of file do you want to use as key in sort? ctime/mtime/ smth else? You can consult `man` page of find to find correct `%XX` instead of `%T@`

Comment: @osgx ctime(?), files are uploaded via FTP... will do.

Comment: Have you tried with `%C@`? - `find . -type f -ctime -3 -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail -n 5 | sed 's/[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1/'`

Comment: @hakre please answer `find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort -r | head -n 10`, and winrar is you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was told that this is the solution:

```
find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort -rn | head -n 10
```

The key point is the printf `%C@` placeholder, which is the `-ctime` one. I found it by reading `man find`.

Result:

```
1336992789.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/05. iPhone/03. iPhone 4G Firmware/5.1.1/iPhone3,1_5.1.1_9B206_Restore.ipsw.filepart
1336928538.0000000000 ./GPS Navigacije/01. Garmin/03. Garmin Other/test.txt
1336922295.0000000000 ./GPS Navigacije/01. Garmin/03. Garmin Other/garmin_kgen_15.exe
1336868365.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2152/E2152_XXJH4_OXFJI2.zip.filepart
1336867426.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E210/E210_XFGH2.rar
1336866301.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2330/FlashTool_E2_R6.zip
1336865921.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2330/E2330_OXFKE2.rar
1336865409.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2230/E2230_XXKC1_CDS.zip
1336865398.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2230/E2230_XXKC1_BIN.zip
1336864949.0000000000 ./Mobilni Telefoni/11. Samsung/1. FLASH FILES/1. SRPSKI HRVATSKI JEZICI/E/E2230/E2230_OXFKC1_CSC.zip
```

---

For a very large list of files, `sort(1)` with pipes might not be optimal for resource usage.

`sort(1)` could be replaced with `perl(1)` and buffer the ten highest entries, only. This has been outlined in *[unix command: how to get top n records](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251851/367456)* for  three, here an adoption for ten records.

It replaces the `sort(1)` and `head(1)` filters:

```
find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | perl -ane '
    BEGIN {@top = ([-1]) x 10}
    if ($F[0] > $top[0][0]) {
        @top = sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} @top[1..9], [$F[0], $_];
    }
    END {print for reverse map {$_->[1]} @top}
'
```

The result is identical.

Comment: You forgot -n to sort. It should be: find . -type f -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort -rn | head -n 10

Comment: Do you know what the default sorting mode is for sort? `-n` sounds fine though

Comment: It's alphabetical but it depends on the locale: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43465/whats-the-default-order-of-linux-sort

Comment: Simplified (and in chronological order): `find -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort | tail`.

Comment: If you want traditional `ls -l` output, you'd send the `head` (or per @tjt263 - `tail`) through a few more pipes: `...|cut -c23-|tr '\n' '\0'|xargs -0 ls -ld` -- I created a script for following large `scp` transfers that I can use with `watch`.

Comment: This is very inefficient for thousands of files, as `sort` maintains a fully sorted list rather than just the top N.

Comment: @hakre I wrote a short python script to do it instead

Comment: @hakre well one requires storing 10 records, and the other requires as many records as you have files. I don't know what you mean about buffering.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Please find the `sort(1)` resource constraints  addressed in the answer now, I updated it. It's even from this Q&A site. Filename portability is not addressed. Maybe a `pathchk(1)` filter. This pays off already on smaller lists for time constraints as I quickly tested.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution to get the x latest modified files in a directory and use it afterwards in a loop to process them further:

```
find "/mnt/user/Movie" -iname '*.mkv' -printf "%C@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -f2- -d" " | tail -10 | tr '\n' '\0' | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
        echo "$file"
    done
```

returns:

```
/mnt/user/Movie/IJ/I (2014)/I (2014).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/AB/B (2010)/B (2010).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/MN/N (1993)/N (1993).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/MN/M (2016)/M (2016).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/KL/K (1984)/K (1984).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/MN/M (1999)/M (1999).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/GH/G (2014)/G (2014).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/MN/M (2002)/M (2002).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/AB/B (2017)/B (2017).mkv
/mnt/user/Movie/CD/D (1997)/D (1997).mkv
```

Change `tail -10` to the amount of files that should be returned. Of course you could replace `-iname '*.mkv'` against `-type f` to cover all files.

Answer (score -4):

Easier:

```
filename=$(ls -t . | head -10)
```

Comment: this isn't a recursive solution; it will only find files in the current directory, not any subdirectories.