# unix command: how to get top n records

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, scripting

I want to get top n records using unix command:

e.g.
input:

- 1 a
- 2 b
- 3 c
- 4 d
- 5 e

output(get top 3):

- 5 e
- 4 d
- 3 c

Current I am doing:

```
cat myfile.txt | sort -k1nr | head -3 > my_output.txt
```

It works fine but when the file gets large, it becomes very slow.

It is slow because it sorts the file completely, while what I need is just the top 3 records.

Is there any command I can use to get the top 3 records?

Comment: See the following for a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074430/how-do-we-sort-faster-using-unix-sort  Unix `sort`, is by far, not the fastest way to sort large files. If your input is that big, you need to look at a different approach. That linked SO post should help.

Comment: Mostly agree about the general case.  However, given a fixed N, you could to this in a dedicated program in single pass over the input keeping the top-N seen.  A priority queue might be handy.  With cheap look at the lowest entry and a count of entries, for each record, if record value > lowest, insert; if count >= limit, delete lowest.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane '
    BEGIN {@top = ([-1]) x 3} 
    if ($F[0] > $top[0][0]) {
        @top = sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]} @top[1,2], [$F[0], $_];
    } 
    END {print for reverse map {$_->[1]} @top}
' << END_DATA
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
END_DATA
```

```
5 e
4 d
3 c
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried changing the order of your command?

Like this.

sort -k1nr myfile.txt | head -3 > my_output.txt

Comment: This won't make any difference in the work `sort` has to do, which is the real problem.

Comment: It will speed up execution on larger files.  Anytime you can eliminate a process, you gain speed.  Allowing sort to work directly on the file without having to read it first works.  Shaves a full minute off sorting a 2GB file.  Granted it took 9 minutes running through cat first, on a 10 year old computer. ;)